# How to rollback nested transactions with Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW in integration tests

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions, integration-testing, rollback

I have several integration tests for various services that extend the following baseclass:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:applicationContext-test.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager", defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{
    //Some setup, filling test data to a HSQLDB-database etc
}
```

For most cases this works fine, but I have a service class which has transactions defined with `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`. It seems these transactions are not rolled back (because they are nested transactions and apparently commit within the "outer" transaction?). The "outer" (test-case level) transaction is rolled back, at least according to test logs. The committed transactions mess up some later tests, because they have changed the test data.

I can get around this by forcing the test to re-create and re-populate the database between tests, but my question is, is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong in my tests? Can the nested transaction be forced to rollback from the testing code?

Comment: there's an Improvement ticket on this https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6908

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, and is one of the main reasons to use REQUIRES_NEW :

- be able to rollback the new transaction, but commit the outer one
- be able to commit the new transaction, but rollback the outer one

re-populate the database between tests is probably the best solution, and I would use this solution for all the tests: this allows tests to check that everything works correctly, including the commit (which could fail due to flushing, deferred constraints, etc.).

But it you really want to rollback the transaction, a solution would be to add a boolean argument `rollbackAtTheEnd` to your service, and rollback the transaction if this argument is true.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll re-populate the database between tests, even if the tests run longer this way. I hadn't thought that the commits could fail, so that's a pro for going with committing tests too. The service in question is a bit of a special case, because it is used during Spring Security login, and in certain cases JPA-exceptions are thrown from service methods, causing the login to fail as the whole transaction is marked for rollback (this is why I chose to use REQUIRES_NEW, so the exceptions wouldn't prevent logging in, another option might be using noRollbackFor in the service).

Comment: Hi I got the same problem but I don't know how to repopulate the database or what are impacts of this? would you tell me about this. thanks

Comment: I wish there was a better solution because it takes a lot of time to recreate the db for each integration test.

Answer (score 6):

I added comment to Spring [improvement ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6908) on this. I'll copy it here too:

I worked around this problem by converting all service methods that were declaratively setup like this

```
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
public Object doSmth() {
  // doSmthThatRequiresNewTx
}
```

to use `TransactionTemplate` instead:

```
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

public Object doSmth() {
  return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                // doSmthThatRequiresNewTx
            }
        });
  }
```

Under tests I configure `transactionTemplate`'s propagation behavior to be `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`, under real app I configure `transactionTemplate`'s propagation behaviour to be `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW`. It works as expected. The limitation of this workaround is that under tests it is not possible to assert the fact that inner transaction is **not** rolledback in an exceptional scenario.

The other solution would be to explicitly delete everything `doSmth()` does in the database in the `@AfterTransaction` method in test. That 'delete' SQL will be run in the new transaction, as its results would be otherwise rolled back routinely by Spring's `TransactionConfiguration` default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do at the end of each tests is to restore the state of all the created/updated/deleted entities and calling this code :

```java
TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
TestTransaction.end();
```

I'm not such a big fan of this solution, but for small unitary tests that require transactions, it can be acceptable.

And to go further, here is complete exemple of what I do :

```java
    @Test
    void feedTable_TxN_should_create_entity() {

        int size = repository.findAll().size();

        LineDataDTO line = new LineDataDTO();
        line.setId(myId);
        // Setters

        service.feedTable_TxN(line);

        assertThat(repository.findAll()).hasSize(size + 1);

        Optional<MyEntity> entityOpt = repository.findById(myId);
        assertThat(entityOpt).isPresent();

        MyEntity entity = gaugeOpt.get();

        assertThat(entity.someGetter()).isEqualTo(someValue);

        repository.delete(entity);
        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        TestTransaction.end();
    }
```

If you want to persist an entity that your service needs you have to do this :

```java
repository.save(entity);

TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
TestTransaction.end();
TestTransaction.start();

// call the service with transactional requires new

// Make assertions

repository.delete(entity);
TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
TestTransaction.end();
```