# Speed up Integration Test Suite

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, h2

I'm trying to speed up running my integration test suite. For every integration test class I have, it recreates the whole in-memory H2 database from scratch before running the tests - which takes up the most time. All methods I'm testing are within a Spring/Hibernate stack.

Is there a way to avoid recreating the db for each test while ensuring the db is in a clean state?

Some methods I'm testing call methods that start new Hibernate transactions - so not sure if it's possible to begin a new transaction before each test and roll everything back after.

Comment: Seems like from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178708/how-to-rollback-nested-transactions-with-propagation-requires-new-in-integration there's no easy way to do so and the best solution is to recreate the db after each test.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behavior (rollback) when using `@Transactional` with  `@RunWith(SpringJunit4TestRunner.class)`.

See the [Integration Testing Chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing) for complete information.

Comment: Does the test rollback db even when it's testing methods that have  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)?

Comment: Also if I place `Transaction` in the class level for each test, will that cause all test methods to rollback?

Comment: No; `REQUIRES_NEW` starts a new transaction which will be committed before returning to the test case. You would need to add a compensating update in the test case to undo it. Yes, class level `@Transactional` makes all test methods transactional.

Comment: Is there a builtin solution with Spring to handle `REQUIRES_NEW`? It could require a lot of work to handle every method the test hits that has 'REQUIRES_NEW`.

Comment: You could write a custom transaction manager that does a rollback instead of commit; it probably wouldn't be too hard; just subclass the `HibernateTransactionManager` and override commit and call `rollback`.